# docker env variable only local

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` that sets environment variables that are common to all environments, whether dev, test, or production ones, but I have to set another environment variable that is only applicable to my development environment, so I can't set it in the `Dockerfile` because such file is managed by the version control, so the change would be deployed to all environments.

How can add an environment variable to a docker container only in my local development environment?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

In case that the env variable can be specified when the image is being used, then just supplying the variable then makes more sense. For instance, if you are locally testing the image, by using the docker cli, you can set the variable with:

```sh
docker run -e KEY=VALUE $image
```

If you are using other tools to test the image, there are always other methods to set env keys.

If it's required for you to have set the variable at build time, you can specify built args inside the Dockerfile.
An example for that would be:

```
FROM someimage:v1

ARG DEV_ONLY_VAR
ENV KEY=$DEV_ONLY_VAR
```

Using this, you can specify the build arg `DEV_ONLY_VAR` in the build command by writing:

```sh
docker build --build-arg DEV_ONLY_VAR=VALUE .
```

Note, even without the `ENV KEY=$DEV_ONLY_VAR` line the build arg will be available like a env variable during build time, on other run steps.
More on build args [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

Comment: (I wouldn't use an `ARG` here; you should be able to run an identical image in all environments.)

Comment: @DavidMaze 
I think the question isn't clear enough to say whether a build arg makes more sense.  
If the variable is used only in runtime, then yes, using an arg isn't really necessary.  
It sounded to me like it could be a arg used during build time, in which case only a build arg makes sense.  Of course there is an argument to make to not have separate images for different environments, but in the end it's up to the developer

Comment: The problem is that the variable is used in production and development as well, but in production, it is set by a mean I don't know. The fact is that it is required by the code but it can't be set by docker in production since it is been set by some other means, but I don't want to set it manually everytime y mount the container.